# How to launch Citrix Xenapp in HTML5 receiver instead of Windows receiver?

Tags: citrix, xenapp, storefront

I'm using Citrix StoreFront Web API and implemented all steps to authenticate request and get list of resources. I also was able to launch app with this code:

```
function performLaunch(resource) {
        var icaFileUrl = resource.launchurl,
            csrfToken = getCookie('CsrfToken'),
            currentTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
            frameId = "launchframe_" + currentTime;

        // To initiate a launch, an ICA file is loaded into a hidden iframe.
        // The ICA file is returned with content type "application/x-ica", allowing it to be intercepted by the Citrix HDX
        // browser plug-in in Firefox/Chrome/Safari. For IE, the user may be prompted to open the ICA file.
        $('#hidden-iframes').append('<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '"></iframe>');

        if (csrfToken != null) {
            icaFileUrl = updateQueryString(icaFileUrl, "CsrfToken", csrfToken);
        }

        // Web Proxy request to load the ICA file into an iframe
        // The request is made by adding
        icaFileUrl = updateQueryString(icaFileUrl, 'launchId', currentTime);
        $("#" + frameId).attr('src', icaFileUrl);

        console.log('perform launch - url: ' + icaFileUrl);
    }
```

But unfortunately it launches app in Citrix Receiver for Windows. But my goal is launch app in browser. We have installed Citrix Receiver for HTML5 on our web server but i don't know how to launch app there.

Answer (score -1):

I got answer from Citrix Employee

http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/370729-how-to-launch-citrix-xenapp-in-html5-receiver-instead-of-windows-receiver/